# Error in login/register system for Android using JSON

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to create a simple login/register system for my Android app. I am following a tutorial by David Kelley (http://davidjkelley.net/?p=48). I downloaded the project David created and it works fine.

However, when I try making a copy of the project and change the relevant lines of code (and package name) to link to my own server, I get errors when I try registering a new user. The two main errors that show up in the logcat are:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'DB_Functions' not found in <b>/home/paid2read13/paid2read.net/android_api/index.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />`

- Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value db of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
...FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 ... java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()... Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.moneytree.RegisterTask.doInBackground(RegisterTask.java:85)...
```

In order for this post to be as useful as possible for me and anyone with similar issues, let me be very clear about what I changed from the code in the website given above:

In all of the classes in the main package (LoginTask.java, RegisterTask, etc.) AND the library (UserFunctions.java and DatabaseHandler.java), I changed `loginURL = "http:// davidjkelley.net/android_api/"` and `registerURL = "http:// davidjkelley.net/android_api/"` to `loginURL = "http:// mydomainname.net/android_api/"` and `registerURL = "http:// mydomainname.net/android_api/"`, respectively. I also changed the database details in config.php to match my details; for the server name I put `mysql.mydomainname.net` because this link brings up my phpmyadmin console and it says `server: mysql.mydomainname.net` at the top of that page. So I think config.php is set up fine.

I don't know why the app "can't find DB_Functions" - I placed the files as instructed at the beginning of the aforementioned tutorial. I'm also not sure what exactly the null pointer issue is referring to.

I've been stuck on this for at least a week and have gone through all related issues; I found nothing similar. I would be very much grateful if anyone could help me with this - I wanna move ahead with my project. Thank you.

Comment: pretty simple: the DB_functions class isn't loaded for whatever reason in your index.php, which caused PHP to dump out an error. And since your android code was expecting json, that PHP error text caused a json parse error. This probably has NOTHING to do with your android code, and is purely a server-side PHP error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. By "loaded" what exactly do you mean? I uploaded DB_FUNCTIONS, DB_CONNECT and CONFIG.php in a folder called include and have index.php in the same directory as include. Doesn't that mean it's "loaded"? I'm sorry, I think I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: just having the files there doesn't do anything. you still have to `include()` or `require()` them in any script which uses the functions they define.

Comment: Thank you very much Marc B. Any way to give you reputation points or thank you on SO?